# Adding API controller in same project as MVC controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

How can an API controller be added to a project with existing MVC (non-API) controllers?

**Problem:**
I've created a very basic "hello world" MVC project with only one model, view, and controller. When I attempt to add the API controller (not using scaffolding), I can't get `using System.Web.Http;` to show in IntelliSense. `using System.Web` will show up, but the `.Http` part is not available. What do I need to do or change?

**Details:**
I'm using VS2013 Express on a Win7 machine.

Comment: MVC4: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990036/how-to-add-web-api-to-an-existing-asp-net-mvc-4-web-application-project

Comment: MVC5: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22401403/add-web-api-to-an-existing-mvc-5-web-application

Comment: @DavidTansey that pointed in the right direction, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[David Tansey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1760479/david-tansey) pointed in the right direction with his comments, but after researching there's more to this than I realized as a beginner.

First, this wasn't available in the using statement because I didn't have a reference for system.web.http in my project. Digging further, I found the reference wasn't even available! So, I had to install using [NuGet Package Manager Console Powershell](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/Reference/Package-Manager-Console-PowerShell-Reference#Install-Package).

In powershell, I can't just do `install-package System.Web.Http`. That package doesn't exist. But, thanks to [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16694695/2658159) that David Tansey's comments pointed to, I noticed I could do `install-package microsoft.aspnet.webapi`. Wonderful! Now `System.Web.Http` is listed under References in my project, and I can write the using statement in my API controller code: `using System.Web.Http;`

For a beginner like me, a lot of steps to go through, and a lot of material to comprehend, to get started.

Comment: are you using webapi2? owin??